# как изменить e-mail на сайте stackoverflow

Tags: поддержка

Недавно зарегистрировался на сайте ru.stackoverflow через вк. Теперь я хочу привязать не свой вк, а gmail на сайт. Как я могу это сделать?
P.s мне нужно привязать email на сайте, по-возможности отвязать вк, а не привязать для уведомлений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, это настраивается [на странице вашей учётной записи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current).

[Добавьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/login-add?returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent) привязку к gmail, потом отвяжите ВК.